# 'ViewBag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, viewbag

I've integrated ASP.NET MVC 3 project into existing Web Forms project. It was working fine, without any error. We have multiple developers working on a project using SVN source control.

MVC3 was integrated in my machine, but when other developers updates project to the latest version, it is not working on their machine.

The only problem is **'ViewBag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.**

Here is a part of the code.

```
Public Class NewsletterMController
Inherits Controller
Protected Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
    ViewBag.CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser()
    MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)
End Sub
```

End Class

As you see, I've inherited "Controller"
Also, I've Imported System.Web.Mvc & System.Web.Abstractions & System.Web.Routing.
In addition, references is well done, and assemblies are registered in Web.config

Anyone has an idea? Why I can't access ViewBag from Web Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewBag` property is introduced in [MVC3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Make sure that you are using the correct version of the `System.Web.Mvc` on all machines.

Comment: we all using version 3.0.0 in all machines. but it only works in the computer that MVC3 was integrated into Web Forms.

Comment: If the `'ViewBag' is not declared` is the only error message what you get it means you have the mvc dll referenced because the `Controller` type is recognized but the `ViewBag` is not there so your project uses the MVC2 dlls instead of the MVC3 ones.

Comment: what is the difference between MVC3 here [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4211) and the one in here [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4612)????

Comment: mine was ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Candidate. just installed ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM and it's working. they seem thay are the same....

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
Mine wase caused by a missing web.config in the Views folder!